# Is there an icon for following/followers?

Tags: icons, social-media

It appears most places apps write those words out.  Am I blind, or is there not yet a commonplace icon that conveys "Number of Followers" or "Number Following" without those words?

Note: I am not looking for the "Follow" (as an imperative) plus sign or the "Currently following" checkmark.